# What happens when you run a block of code faster than it can process the code in that block?

Tags: c#

Say you have a block of code that you run every 100 milliseconds, but the code within that block takes 500 milliseconds to run. Does it complete processing the block of code?

```
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    OnTick();
}

public void OnTick(){ //Block of code that take 500 milliseconds to process }
```

Comment: This is sync, of course it will "complete".

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say it does. What is your *actual* problem? What are you trying to do? It *is* possible to run something in the background periodically - that's what timers do. It's also possible to prevent a new execution if the previous one hasn't completed

Answer (score 7):

This code does not run every 100 milliseconds, it waits 100 milliseconds between every iteration. Important difference.

You're synchronously calling that code, so the next iteration of that loop will occur after `OnTick()` returns.

Now if this were an actual timer tick (as opposed to a `Thread.Sleep()`) or the 500 ms of work would happen on a different thread, this would change.

Answer (score 6):

Your loop does not run a 500-millisecond block of code every 100 milliseconds; it runs 500-millisecond blocks with delays of 100 milliseconds between them. Each iteration takes 600 milliseconds:

[image: SleepRun]

You can make a piece of code that starts a new code block every 100 milliseconds. If the code takes 500 milliseconds of CPU time, the system becomes overloaded as soon as the number of available cores gets exhausted.

If, on the other hand, the code in the 500-millisecond block spends most of its time sleeping or waiting for I/O in a separate thread, the system will continue spawning new threads until the maximum is reached, or the memory is exhausted.

Comment: I believe this answer addresses the issue the OP *meant* to ask.

Answer (score 3):

That depends entirely on the implementation of `OnTick()` - if it is synchronous, and doesn't spawn any background threads (etc) then your loop will wait 100ms, spend 500ms running `OnTick()`, then (and only then) wait another 100ms, before running `OnTick()` again

Answer (score 0):

C#, like most other programming languages, uses sequential execution.

That means one statement is executed, then the next one is executed.

That means in your example the code waits 100ms, then it does something for 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop waits 100 milli seconds and then calls onTick(). So the next iteration will occurs after onTick() returns.It is sequential.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else already explained, your code simply executes one statement after the other.

I assume the actual question is how to run something every 100ms *without* overlapping executions. Otherwise you could use a [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) directly.

One option is to use `Task.Delay` to await 100ms asynchronously inside a loop.

```
public async Task RunTimer(Action act,TimeSpan delay,CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay,token);
        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            act();
        }
    }   
}
```

The cancellation token allows cancelling the timer. Eg :

```
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
var delay=TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
var timerTask= RunTimer(()=>someMethod(),delay,cts.Token);
...
cts.Cancel();
```